# What is a Multietude™ word?

Tags: pattern, word-property

This puzzle is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What%20is%20%22%20%22Word%22%20-missing%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Multietude™** word.
Here is a list of Multietude™ and not-Multietude™ words:
[image]

And CSV version:

```
Multietude;Not-Multietude
Spy;Infiltrator
Baby;Boy
Mouse;Cat
Louse;Beetle
Penny;Clay
Domino;Card
Puppy;Hay
```

**QUESTION:** What is the rule to tell whether a word is a **Multietude™** word or not?

Comment: Here we go again...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Multietude Word is:

> a noun whose **plural involves modifying the word in some additional way** than just merely adding an 's' on the end.

For the examples given:

> SPY --> SP**IES**,
>  BABY --> BAB**IES**,
>  MOUSE --> M**ICE**,
>  LOUSE --> L**ICE**,
>  PENNY --> PENN**IES**,
>  DOMINO --> DOMINO**ES** (although 'DOMINOS' is also accepted [by most dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/domino)),
>  PUPPY --> PUPP**IES**

In contrast, the words which are Not Multietude Words:

> are pluralised just by adding an 's': INFILTRATORS, BOYS, CATS, BEETLES, CLAYS, CARDS, HAYS.

As for the title:

> 'Multitude' (without the 'e' in the middle) is a word describing a large number of a particular thing. However, here our 'large number' (i.e. plural) has been **modified** (with the addition of the 'e') just like our valid cases...

Comment: This is correct!  One other property of a Multietude word is that the plural form of the word always contains the letter "i" followed by the letter "e".

Comment: @KyleWilliamson Ah, I see - just not necessarily consecutively...